# How can I position the element at very precise pixel on image using Top and Left CSS property

Tags: html, css, image, onclick, pixel

I want to display a dot at specific pixel on image click. I'm displaying it by giving top and left values in %. What happening is the dot isn't moving when clicked another pixel present inside the dot.
When click outside then it is moving. I don't understand why this is happening.

May be it is because there is very small change in top and left values for each pixel.

I've updated CSS for displaying dot within the circle

```
.hObiiS{
  border: solid 1px #303030 !important; 
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: none !important; 
  height: 9px !important; 
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  width: 9px !important; 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.hObiiS::before{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px; 
    background-color: rgb(224, 1, 1);
    border-radius: 50%;
}

<div class="hObiiS" style="top: 25.4601%; left: 58.6382%;"></div>
```

Can someone please provide solution to move dot per pixel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem solution.

```js
let container  = document.querySelector('img');
let dot = document.getElementById('dot');

document. addEventListener('click', function( e ) {
if (container === event.target && container.contains(e. target)) {
  
  var parentPosition = getPosition(container);
    var xPosition = e.clientX - parentPosition.x - (dot.clientWidth / 2);
    var yPosition = e.clientY - parentPosition.y - (dot.clientHeight / 2);
     
    dot.style.left = xPosition + "px";
    dot.style.top = yPosition + "px";
}
});






// Helper function to get an element's exact position
function getPosition(el) {
  var xPos = 0;
  var yPos = 0;
 
  while (el) {
    if (el.tagName == "BODY") {
      // deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and page scroll
      var xScroll = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      var yScroll = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 
      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - xScroll + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - yScroll + el.clientTop);
    } else {
      // for all other non-BODY elements
      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    }
 
    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPos,
    y: yPos
  };
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  cursor: "crosshair";
}
#dot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate(100, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img width="200px" alt="" src="https://img.rawpixel.com/s3fs-private/rawpixel_images/website_content/upwk62143495-wikimedia-image.jpg?w=800&dpr=1&fit=default&crop=default&q=65&vib=3&con=3&usm=15&bg=F4F4F3&ixlib=js-2.2.1&s=218f80fbd029cd0fa69b8597ef4928c0" />
    <span id="dot" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mudasirh/pen/QWQoPwE?editors=1111)

Your mouse click position (e.clientX and e.clientY) is relative to your browser's top-left corner that's why your click position is not accurate. You can study the details explanation in this article.
[Move Element to Click Position](https://www.kirupa.com/snippets/move_element_to_click_position.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the dot from stopping the click going through to the image.

You can use pointer-events for that.

Here's a simple example:

```css
.container {
  position relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 30vmin;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.dot {
  background: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><img onclick="alert('I saw the click');" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300">
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want my dot to display at the position where clicked !!

Comment: Yes, I assumed you have some JavaScript for that already. I was just showing you how to make sure that the click event gets passed to the image. So  if you already have the movement, which is sounds from your question that you have, then just add the pointer-events: none to the dot. If still stuck please post enough code for us to run and see the problem.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I'm getting the click event and also pixels just dot is not moving when pixel is already inside the dot.

Comment: I'm using react-image-annotation-with-zoom library for all this operations. I've updated some css according to my need. But still unable to mark at precise level .

Comment: So we need to see the code you are using to place the dot.

Comment: Updated the question.. please check

Comment: Where is your code for moving the dot - your question said that that worked when the click was on the img but not on the dot? Or are you saying you don't have any code to move the dot whether the click was outside or inside the dot? I was expecting some JavaScript.

Comment: I've used the library . It handles the positioning.

Comment: What library? Your question doesn't tag a library as such.